# Reading a multi-line output stops after reading after first line in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

```
IFS="\n"
for line in $text; do 
    read -a array <<< $line
    echo ${array[0]}
done
```

content of $text :

```
123 456
abc def
hello world
```

expected result :

```
123
456
abc
def
hello
world
```

real result :

```
123
```

I have doubts that the read -a is the one that stops the for loop!
How i can solve this problem ?

Comment: [I can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/AlKHzN). Also your `$line` variable would be better named `$word` since your `for/in` iterates over words (split around `$IFS`), which is why your `echo ${array[0]}` will (should) output every word rather than the first word of each line.

Comment: I have forgotten to mention the IFS in the code above ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to modify `IFS` to a new line character and then loop over lines using a `for` loop. Just use the `read` command to read from the string.

Instead of reading the whole line to an array, you could use separate placeholder variables to store each row in your line. Something like below assuming the shell is a non-POSIX shell like `bash`, because the native POSIX `sh` shell does not support arrays.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

text='123 456
abc def
hello world'

declare -a arrayStorage
while read -r row1 row2; do
    arrayStorage+=( "$row1" )  
    arrayStorage+=( "$row2" )  
done <<< "$text"
```

and printing the array using `printf` below should produce the output as you need.

```
printf '%s\n' "${arrayStorage[@]}"
```

If instead the `text` is a output of a command being run, use a process-substitution syntax on the command as below. This way, the output of command is connected to stdin of the `read` command

```
done < <(somecommand)
```

Or if the content is just a file, use the file re-direction to slurp its contents

```
done < filename
```

Answer (score 0):

inside of giving zero(0) please give variable name

```
for line in $text; do 
    read -a array <<< $line
    echo ${array[index]}
done
```

Comment: even if i put the index instead of a number it won't work :(